# Pronunciation of "there, their and they're"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, homophones

I know that the words *there*, *their*, and *they're* are homophones, but I can't help but think that *their* has a slight /j/ between /e/ and /r/  (/ðer/).
This thought didn't just come to me out of nowhere- for instance, I clearly can hear it in the [forvo](https://forvo.com/search/their/en_usa/) American English sample pronunciation.

Is THERE any grain of truth in my words or am I a bit deaf?

Comment: You need a recording of the same person saying all three words before you can conclude anything.

Comment: There can be individual differences in how different people pronounce them, and in how the same person pronounces them in different contexts, but they're arbitrary and cancel out over speech groups. This is true of a lot of other speech phenomena and accounts for how we can be so good at recognizing others' voices.

Comment: Words in isolation can be pronounced more carefully and with greater care but I assure you, in fast connected speech no one would be able to tell the difference. Otherwise how would you explain why so many native speakers misspell these words; it's like *your* and *you're* the same thing.

Comment: At least 55% of Americans don't distinguish between Mary, merry, and marry.[See the Harvard dialect survey](http://dialect.redlog.net/)—the survey was 20 years ago, and this percentage has surely increased.  I would expect that a significantly larger percentage don't distinguish between *there*, *their*, and *they're*. So if you hear this distinction when you listen to most Americans, my guess is that you're imagining it.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thank you for using common sense.  I only have this slight doubt.  'Homophone' describes a word that sounds the same as another word (or so the Cambridge English Dictionary defines it).  So strictly 'they're' cannot be described as a 'homophone' with/of 'there' or 'their'.  Perhaps it could be described as 'homophonic' in relation to 'there' and 'their', but the same dictionary doesn't have that adjectival form  of the noun.

Comment: @Tuffy For me it's still a homophone. The contraction "they're" is spoken as if it were a single word, we don't hear the apostrophe and we don't hear it as two words, even though we know it is composed by "they" and "are". At least that's how I interpret it.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A  That's a fair argument.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that the words *there*, *their*, and *they're* are homophones

Yes.

> but I can't help but think that *their* has a slight /j/ between /e/
> and /r/  (/ðer/).

It’s possible, but no more so than for *there* and *they’re.* I don’t think you’re imagining things, but I also wouldn’t recommend taking any special efforts to pronounce this word this way.

For American English speakers, there is generally no phonemic contrast between the vowel in *there/their/they’re* and the vowel in *they*/*say*/*fade*/*male*/*mail*. (This holds regardless of whether we’re talking about an accent with or without the Mary-marry-merry merger.)

But phonetically, you’re less likely to hear a /j/-like glide when the vowel is followed by /r/ with no intervening word boundary, and more likely to hear a glide when the vowel is word-final, followed by a vowel, or followed by most other consonants, like /p b m t d n k g s z f v θ ð tʃ dʒ/. For me, the /j/-like off glide of the vowel /e/ is also suppressed to some extent before a following /l/ (which I pronounce as “dark l”, [ɫ]), but I don’t know how common this is or the details of how it works (I do distinguish pairs like *fail* and *fell*).